# How to lock some excel columns as readonly for npoi excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

unable to set npoi excel sheet as read only for some columns
I have tried create freeze (sheet1.CreateFreezePane(0, 1, 0, 1);) but not working

```
    public void WriteExcelWithNPOI(DataTable dt, String extension,string MSANAme,string CheckValue)
    {

        IWorkbook workbook;

        if (extension == "xlsx")
        {
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        }
        else if (extension == "xls")
        {
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("This format is not supported");
        }

        ISheet sheet1 = workbook.CreateSheet("Sheet 1");
        //make a header row
        IRow row1 = sheet1.CreateRow(0);



        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
        {

            ICell cell = row1.CreateCell(j);
            String columnName = dt.Columns[j].ToString();
            cell.SetCellValue(columnName);
        }

        //loops through data
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            IRow row = sheet1.CreateRow(i + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {

                ICell cell = row.CreateCell(j);
                String columnName = dt.Columns[j].ToString();
                cell.SetCellValue(dt.Rows[i][columnName].ToString());
            }
        }

        using (var exportData = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Response.Clear();
            workbook.Write(exportData);
            if (extension == "xlsx") //xlsx file format
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}" + MSANAme + CheckValue+ ".xlsx"));

                Response.BinaryWrite(exportData.ToArray());
            }
            else if (extension == "xls")  //xls file format
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename="+ MSANAme + CheckValue + ".xls"));
                Response.BinaryWrite(exportData.GetBuffer());
            }
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

all the excel columns are editable, need to set some of the columns as readonly. please help.
all the excel columns are editable, need to set some of the columns as readonly. please help.
all the excel columns are editable, need to set some of the columns as readonly. please help.

Comment: freezepane is to stop scrolling, you need to protect the areas.

Comment: yes, I found that out later. npoi version is v2.30. please let me know how to lock some columns in excel and allow others as editable. thanks

Comment: I dont use npoi, you would need to look at the documentation

Answer (score 2):

Am going to assume your code is working, so am taking it as reference and editing it.

```
    public void WriteExcelWithNPOI(DataTable dt, String extension,string MSANAme,string CheckValue)
    {

        IWorkbook workbook;

        if (extension == "xlsx")
        {
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        }
        else if (extension == "xls")
        {
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("This format is not supported");
        }

        ISheet sheet1 = workbook.CreateSheet("Sheet 1");
        //make a header row
        IRow row1 = sheet1.CreateRow(0);

        var cellStyleForLocked = workbook.CreateCellStyle(); //create the style in the beginning itself
        cellStyleForLocked.IsLocked = true;

        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
        {

            ICell cell = row1.CreateCell(j);
            String columnName = dt.Columns[j].ToString();
            cell.SetCellValue(columnName);
        }

        //loops through data
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            IRow row = sheet1.CreateRow(i + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {

                ICell cell = row.CreateCell(j);
                String columnName = dt.Columns[j].ToString();

                if(j < 6) //set the locked style only for first 6 columns.
                    cell.CellStyle = cellStyleForLocked;

                cell.SetCellValue(dt.Rows[i][columnName].ToString());
            }
        }

        using (var exportData = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Response.Clear();
            workbook.Write(exportData);
            if (extension == "xlsx") //xlsx file format
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}" + MSANAme + CheckValue+ ".xlsx"));

                Response.BinaryWrite(exportData.ToArray());
            }
            else if (extension == "xls")  //xls file format
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename="+ MSANAme + CheckValue + ".xls"));
                Response.BinaryWrite(exportData.GetBuffer());
            }
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Hopefully it works for you!

Comment: Tried this while iterating "dt.Columns.Count", still not working, please help. And I need to lock only first 6 columns in excel and leave the 7th column editable. please help. Thanks

Comment: you have to create different cell styles, in the beginning of the function, not while iterating. Then, while iterating, assign the cell style you want for the particular row and cell.

Comment: @Yuvaraj77, do you still need code sample for different cell styles?

Comment: Tried it but still the issue persists please send code samples. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

VB.net
blow code is worked

```
Private Sub WriteExcelNPoi(ByVal extension As String)
        Dim workbook As IWorkbook
        Dim DT As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Dim strFilename As String = String.Empty

        DT.Rows.Clear()
        DT.Columns.Clear()
        DT.Columns.Add("A")
        DT.Columns.Add("B")
        DT.Columns.Add("C")
        DT.Columns.Add("D")
        DT.Columns.Add("E")
        DT.Columns.Add("F")
        DT.Columns.Add("G")
        DT.Columns.Add("H")
        DT.Columns.Add("I")
        DT.Columns.Add("J")
        Try
            Dim drow As DataRow
            For i As Integer = 0 To 3
                drow = DT.NewRow
                drow("A") = "00" & i.ToString
                drow("B") = "001" & i.ToString
                drow("C") = "001" & i.ToString
                drow("D") = "001" & i.ToString
                drow("E") = "001" & i.ToString
                drow("F") = "001" & i.ToString
                drow("G") = "001" & i.ToString
                drow("H") = "001" & i.ToString
                drow("I") = "001" & i.ToString
                drow("J") = "001" & i.ToString
                DT.Rows.Add(drow)
            Next

            If extension = "xlsx" Then
                workbook = New XSSFWorkbook()
                strFilename = "SampleExport_" & Now().ToLongTimeString & ".xlsx"
            ElseIf extension = "xls" Then
                workbook = New HSSFWorkbook()
                strFilename = "SampleExport_" & Now().ToLongTimeString & ".xls"
            Else
                Throw New Exception("This format is not supported")
            End If

            Dim sheet1 As ISheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Sheet 1")
            Dim row1 As IRow = sheet1.CreateRow(0)

            'cell style locked
            Dim cellStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle()
            cellStyle.IsLocked = True
            cellStyle.FillBackgroundColor = IndexedColors.Grey25Percent.Index
            'cellStyle.FillPattern = FillPattern.SolidForeground

            'cell style unlock
            Dim unlockCellstyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle()
            unlockCellstyle.IsLocked = False

            'set header for excel
            For j As Integer = 0 To DT.Columns.Count - 1
                Dim cell As ICell = row1.CreateCell(j)
                Dim columnName As String = DT.Columns(j).ToString()
                cell.SetCellValue(columnName)
            Next

            'set value cell excel
            For i As Integer = 0 To DT.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim row As IRow = sheet1.CreateRow(i + 1)

                For j As Integer = 0 To DT.Columns.Count - 1
                    Dim cell As ICell = row.CreateCell(j)
                    Dim columnName As String = DT.Columns(j).ToString()
                    If j < 6 Then 'lock range not edit data
                        cell.CellStyle = cellStyle
                    Else
                        cell.CellStyle = unlockCellstyle 'unlock range edit data
                    End If
                    cell.SetCellValue(DT.Rows(i)(columnName).ToString())
                Next
            Next
            'Protect the sheet
            sheet1.ProtectSheet("hoang")

            'download file excel
            Using exportData = New MemoryStream()
                Response.Clear()
                workbook.Write(exportData)

                If extension = "xlsx" Then
                    Response.ContentType = "application/force-download"
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;    filename=" & strFilename)
                    Response.BinaryWrite(exportData.ToArray())
                ElseIf extension = "xls" Then
                    Response.ContentType = "application/force-download"
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & strFilename)
                    Response.BinaryWrite(exportData.ToArray())
                End If
                exportData.Close()
                Response.[End]()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("This format is not supported")
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Hopefully it works for you!